# Javascript Array Push and Display

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, laravel

I am doing a Laravel project with editable inline with select option however I want I manage to query the brands and I want to display the array after I push it in the source. Please help

```
var brand = [];
data_brand.forEach(function(element) {   
    var branddetails = {value: element.id, text: element.brand_name}; 
    brand.push(branddetails);
});
$(function(){
    $('#brand').editable({
        value: 2,    
        source: [

            //I want to output like this {value: 1, text: 'Active'},
            brand.values() // this code does not work
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you not use the array directly? `, source: brand`

Comment: whats the error you are getting? 
Without iterating you cannot get the values of Array/List.

Comment: can you share what you are getting in `data_brand`? thanks

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
source: brand.map(item => item)
```

or simply:

```
source: brand
```

Comment: That makes no sense. `forEach` does not return anything.

Comment: did you mean `brand`?

Comment: @SivaKondapiVenkata, yes, edited. although collections should be named plural.

Answer (score 0):

In order to display the array elements, use `loop`.

Example-

```js
let branddetails = [{value: 1, text: "something" }];

branddetails.forEach(brand => console.log(brand));
```

-- Edit --

Instead of creating array and then getting the pushed element, you can directly add the element itself in the `source` array.

```
let branddetails;
data_brand.forEach(function (element) {
  branddetails = { value: element.id, text: element.brand_name };
});
$(function () {
  $('#brand').editable({
    value: 2,
    source: [
      branddetails 
    ]
  });
});
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to "display" the elements, they want to use them within `.editable({`

Comment: Ok, so now your edit will only contain the last value from `data_brand`

Comment: @freedomn-m I tried but it does not shows the values.

Answer (score 0):

`brand` is an array and you since `source` also expecting the array, You can try like this

`source: [...brand]`